# Вопрос по регуляркам в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка с произвольным текстом, нужно найти сколько раз в этой строке повторяется определённое слово.

Пробую с помощью

```
re.findall(f"\W{word}\W", line)
```

Всё работает правильно, единственное он не берёт в учёт слова в самом начале строки и в конце.
Я ещё слаб регулярках, подскажите, как правильно сделать?
В строке может быть полный мусор, главное чтобы слово не было подстрокой какого-то другого слова. Надеюсь, внятно объяснил, а то в 5 утра это тяжело :)

Comment: re.findall(f"\b{word}\b", line)

Comment: Да, я это пытался делать, он ничего не ищет вообще. 0 результатов.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример текста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [4]: text="""word, another word
   ...: yet another word
   ...: final word"""
   ...:

In [5]: print(text)
word, another word
yet another word
final word

In [6]: re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format('word'), text)
Out[6]: ['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']
```

или

```
In [8]: word = 'word'

In [9]: re.findall(f'\\b{word}\\b', text)
Out[9]: ['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']
```

Comment: Второй вариант сработал. Спасибо. А что меняется при добавлении второго слеша?

Comment: Backslash используется для ввода спецсимволов, поэтому для того чтобы ввести сам backslash его надо экранировать им же

Answer (score 1):

Используйте "raw string literal" ("сырой" строковой литерал) вместе с префиксом интерполяции `f`:

```
re.findall(rf'\b{word}\b', text)
           ^^
```

Нет нужды использовать знак обратной косой черты больше, чем нужно, так как в таких строковых литералах не поддерживаются строковые escape-последовательности (r'\n' — это строка из двух символов, знака `\` и `n`).

Пример кода:

```
>>> import re
>>> text='wordly wordliness word'
>>> word = 'word'
>>> print(re.findall(rf'\b{word}\b', text))
['word']
```